# Simrank Implementation(in-neighbor calculation)

Tags: python, python-2.7, graph, statistics

```
for i in range(0,len(G)):
        for j in range(0,len(G[i])):          
            if i!=j:
                init=0
                for k in range(0,len(G[:,i])):
                    if G[k,i]==1:
                        row=k
                        cnt1=cnt1+1
                        for l in range(0,len(G[:,j])):
                            if G[l,j]==1:
                                col=l
                                cnt2=cnt2+1
                                init=init+R[row,col]     
                cnt = cnt1 + cnt2
                S[i,j] = lam*C*init/cnt
```

In this code I am trying to print the similarity score between nodes in a graph.But the problem is it is not calculating the in-neighbours properly.I tried everything.Could you help?
Link-http://hanj.cs.illinois.edu/pdf/cikm09_pzhao.pdf
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(max_iter):

    for u, v in itertools.product(nodes,nodes):
        if u is v: continue

        if directed:
            u_ns, v_ns = G.predecessors(u), G.predecessors(v)
        else:
            u_ns, v_ns = G.neighbors(u), G.neighbors(v)
```

this is how you can calculate in-neighbors using the networkx library.
note-G is the graph object created from adjacency matrix
for more details read the docs of the library